# Converting java.util.Date to java.time.LocalDateTime using ZoneId.systemDefault()

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, java-8

I am having trouble converting a `java.util.Date` into an `java.time.LocalDateTime` and I am having a really weird effect with regard to the timezone:

```
Date date = new Date(-3155677200000L); // 1870-01-01T00:00:00.000+0100

LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault()); // 1869-12-31T23:53:28
```

The time is really off. 6 minutes and 32 seconds, which is annoying, because it also changes the date and even year here.

It has to do with `ZoneId.systemDefault()`, if I use a `ZoneOffset` it works.

Why is that? Is it a bug in the JDK? In only seems to happen for dates before year 1893.

`ZoneId.systemDefault()` is Europe/Berlin (CET, +01:00)

Similarly:

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(1870, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

prints:

```
1870-01-01T00:00+00:53:28[Europe/Berlin]
```

expected result:

```
1870-01-01T00:00+01:00:00[Europe/Berlin]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conversion is correct according to the IANA rules. The Europe/Berlin rule starts with this line:

```
Zone    Europe/Berlin   0:53:28 -   LMT 1893 Apr
```

You started off with 1869-12-31T23:00:00Z, so the local time is 1869-12-31T23:53:28.

No bugs here - just a mistaken expectation.

Comment: So actually the java.util.Date representation is wrong as it should be 1869-12-31T23:53:28.000+0100?

Comment: @user2907078: I don't know what you mean by "the java.util.Date representation is wrong" - the `Date` value is just the instant in time, which is 1869-12-31T23:00:00Z, or equivalently 1870-01-01T00:00:00.000+0100. That's the value for the milliseconds-since-epoch value of -3155677200000L. If you're asking whether -3155677200000L is wrong, we don't know - we don't know where you got it from.